# creating instance and installing git using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

i created an ec2 instance using ansible but after creating instance it is not downloading git package.
my code:

```
ec2:
       key_name: "{{ key }}"
       aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
       region: "{{ aws_region }}"
       image: ami-2322b6123
       instance_type: t2.micro

   - name: install  git
     yum: name=git state=present
```

so , can i please know if there is way to install a package after creating ec2 instance using ansible?

Answer (score 2):

After launching the EC2 instance, you have to run the play (to install git) in the newly launched instance, not in the control host. You have to register the just launched, add it to the host inventory and then install the package. Just follow the example in Ansible documentation: [ec2 module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html)

```
- name: Create a instance
  ...
  ...
  tasks:
    - name: Launch instance
      ec2:
       key_name: "{{ key }}"
       aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
       region: "{{ aws_region }}"
       image: ami-2322b6123
       instance_type: t2.micro
      register: ec2

    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=launched
      with_items: '{{ec2.instances}}'

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for: host={{ item.public_dns_name }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
      with_items: '{{ec2.instances}}'

- name: Configure instance(s)
  hosts: launched
  gather_facts: True
  ...
  tasks:
   - name: install  git
     yum: name=git state=present
```